# Beelink SER6 Pro VEST Mini PC with GAN charger can only boot with acpi=off

Tags: boot, acpi

I bought a Beelink SER6 Pro VEST and installed `Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS` with the original charger. It worked well without any problems. However, I'd like to use a light-weight GAN charger, so I try to use my 140W GaN charger but it doesn't boot.

I have tried `acpi=ht`, `acpi=noirq`, `acpi=strict`, `pci=noacpi`, `noapic`, `nolapic` but none of them can boot successfully. Only `acpi=off` works.

Is there other options I can try?